# Computation of the expectation $E(2^{X-2})$ for $X$ negative binomial

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value, negative-binomial

If I have a coin with $\ 0.6$ probability of getting  $\ H $and I throw it until I get  $\ H $ for the second time. If $\ Y $ is the number of $\ T$ I get and $\ 2^Y $ is my revenue. how do I calculate my revenue expectancy ?

If I set $\ X $ as my total number of throws then $\ Y = X-2 $

I know $\ X \sim NB(2,0.6)  $ so $\ E[X] = \frac{2}{0.6} = \frac{10}{3} $

$$\ E[2^Y] = E[2^{x-2}]$$

but now I need some algebraic manipulation so I'll have something like $\ E[aX + b] $ ?

I also tried different direction based on the probability function of negative binomial $\ P\{X = i\} = { i-1 \choose r-1 } (1-p)^{i-r} \cdot p^r$ $$\ E[2^Y] = E[2^{x-2}] = \sum_{x} g(x)\cdot p_x(x) = \sum_{i=2}^\infty 2^i \cdot {i-1\choose r-1} \cdot 0.4^{i-2} \cdot 0.6^2 = \sum_{i=2}^\infty 2^i \cdot { i-1 \choose 1 }\cdot 0.4^{i-2} \cdot 0.6^2 = \sum_{i=2}^\infty 2^i \cdot(i-1) \cdot 0.4^{i-2}\cdot 0.6^2$$

Any suggestions?

Comment: Here are two basic facts to enable you to conclude: $$\sum_{i=2}^\infty 2^i(i-1)(0.4)^{i-2}=4\sum_{j=0}^\infty(j+1)(0.8)^j$$ and, for every $|x|<1$, $$\sum_{j=0}^\infty(j+1)x^j=\frac d{dx}\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k=\frac d{dx}\frac1{1-x}=\frac1{(1-x)^2}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Took me a while to understand what you did there in the first line algebrically. Could you explain the second line?I have this identity I know $$\ \sum_{i=0}^\infty x^i = \frac{1}{1-x} $$ so not sure how did you use it for $\ \sum_{j=0}^\infty (j+1)x^j $ ? Does it mean the final answer should be just $\ \frac{1}{0.2^2} $ ?

Comment: As is written, "what I did" is considering the derivative of the series you know. // It seems all this is rather pointing to a "final answer" equal to $4/(0.2)^2=100$.

Comment: Two things: first, in your formula $2^i$ should read $2^{i-2}$; secondly, you forgot to take into account the factor $(0.6)^2$. Correcting the first mistake divides $100$ by $4$, correcting the second mistake multiplies it by $(0.6)^2$. And $(100\div4)\cdot(0.6)^2=$ ...